# My Python web crawler loops through a list but writes over and over in the same field in my SQL Database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I working on web crawler, which gathers brand names for my an save the name in a SQL database. Since I'm programming with Python I chose Django to build my GUI, so I also use Django's ability to connect to SQL databases. Somehow when I loop through the list of brands, in the end it's aways only the last brand name which get stored in the database.

My suspicion is that I didn't understand how the auto field of my brand class is working. So I will show you, how my brand class looks like, I will not post the whole web crawler, cause it's not important how I code that one, in the end the crawler return a list, and then I will show you the function saveBrands(), which should store the brand names in my database.

QUESTION: What do I need to do, that `companyid = models.AutoField(db_column='CompanyID', primary_key=True)` increases automatically? Or isn't that the problem?

Thanks in Advance!

This is my table model in my models.py:

```
class Companies(models.Model):
companyid = models.AutoField(db_column='CompanyID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
companyname = models.CharField(db_column='CompanyName', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
comfair = models.TextField(db_column='ComFair', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. This field type is a guess.
comecological = models.TextField(db_column='ComEcological', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. This field type is a guess.
concerns_conercernid = models.ForeignKey('Concerns', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Concerns_ConercernID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
companiecountry = models.CharField(db_column='CompanieCountry', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'Companies'

def saveCompany(self):
    self.save()
```

This is my Crawler-Class:

```
class crawler():

def showCrawledBrands(self):
    ...
    return(brandLst)


def saveBrands(self):

    brandLst = self.showCrawledBrands()
    tabelle = Companies()

    for brand in brandLst:
        tabelle.companyname = brand
        tabelle.comfair = 0
        tabelle.comecological = 0
        print(tabelle.companyname, tabelle.comfair, tabelle.comecological)
        tabelle.saveCompany()
        print("Saved")
```

Comment: What's the point of the `saveCompany` method?

Comment: The saveCompany method saves the Class-Instance-Object of the cumpany-class to the SQL-Database.

Comment: But all it does is call another, existing, method. What's the point of defining a method that only does that? Why don't you just call `tabelle.save()` directly?

Comment: Ah, okay, now I understand your quest. Well, u r right. I can't remember why I did it like that. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an object `tabelle = Companies()`. An instance of a model class represents a **row** in the DB. You have to create the object inside the loop (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects).

```
for brand in brandLst:
    tabelle = Companies()
    tabelle.companyname = brand
    tabelle.comfair = 0
    tabelle.comecological = 0
    print(tabelle.companyname, tabelle.comfair, tabelle.comecological)
    tabelle.saveCompany()
    print("Saved")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the solution!  I though the instance of an class is the whole table, but now I understand: The class is the whole table (kinda) and the instance of a class is a row. Again, thanks!